# Serving Angular JS HTML templates from S3 and CloudFront - CORS problems

Tags: amazon-s3, angularjs, jsonp, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having a doozy of a time trying to serve static HTML templates from Amazon CloudFront.

I can perform a `jQuery.get` on Firefox for my HTML hosted on S3 just fine. The same thing for CloudFront returns an `OPTIONS 403 Forbidden`. And I can't perform an ajax get for either S3 or CloudFront files on Chrome. I assume that Angular is having the same problem.

I don't know how it fetches remote templates, but it's returning the same error as a `jQuery.get`. My CORS config is fine according to Amazon tech support and as I said I can get the files directly from S3 on Firefox so it works in one case.

My question is, how do I get it working in all browsers and with CloudFront and with an Angular templateUrl?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24459590/652693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Amazon does not currently support SSL and CORS on CloudFront or S3, which is the crux of the problem. Other CDNs like Limelight or Akamai allow you to add your SSL cert to a CNAME which circumvents the problem, but Amazon does not allow that either and other CDNs are cost prohibitive. The best alternative seems to be serving the html from your own server on your domain. Here is a solution for Angular and Rails: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180837/256066

Answer (score 1):

For people coming from google, a bit more

Turns out Amazon actually does support CORS via SSL when the CORS settings are on an S3 bucket. The bad part comes in when cloudfront caches the headers for the CORS response. If you're fetching from an origin that could be mixed http & https you'll run into the case where the allowed origin from CloudFront will say http but you want https. That of course causes the browser to blow up. To make matters worse, CloudFront will cache slightly differing versions if you accept compressed content. Thus if you try to debug this with curl, you'll think all is well then find it isn't in the browser (try passing --compressed to curl).

One, admittedly frustrating, solution is just ditch the entire CloudFront thing and serve directly from the S3 bucket.