# Sprockets' asset_path is not returning the digested path of an HTML asset in production.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've got some template HTML and JS files which are in the assets directory, structured like this:

```
app
 - assets
   - templates 
     - my_template.html
   - javascripts
     - application.js
     - main.js.erb
```

Where `application.js` contains the standard sprockets directive: `//= require main`

and `main.js.erb` contains a reference to the path for `my_template.html`: 
`main.js.erb`: 
    // Some code here ... 
    return {
        pathToTemplate: "<%= asset_path 'my_template.html' %>"
    }
    // More code here ...

In development, this works great. `main.js.erb` is evaluated to the following:

```
// Some code here ...
return {
    pathToTemplate: "assets/my_template.html"
}
// More code here
```

In production, assets are precompiled (gzipped and whitespace removed), and a fingerprint is appended to the filename.

Production `main.js.erb` ***should*** look like:

```
pathToTemplate: "assets/my_template-610dd79b5bb3c20d14b81baa891fc9dd.html"
```

but is instead the same as in development.

Does Sprockets need to be configured to also fingerprint HTML files? Perhaps it's a bug, because it's generating a 
manifest file with fingerprinted paths, but asset_path is returning a non-fingerprinted path in `main.js.erb`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Sprockets itself no longer implements `asset_path` - this is a Rails helper provided by Action View.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cd0b6233ae22f6bc8407d240eb2f933ca122f86d/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L120

This question should answer the rest of it for you:

[Ruby on Rails 4 and usage of asset_path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951139/ruby-on-rails-4-and-usage-of-asset-path)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I take all of the folders in the templates directory, and place them in the assets/images folder, then asset_path works as expected and returns fingerprinted paths. I expect this is a Rails bug.

Comment: We call that a feature around here ;-)