# Rails - Render asset javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

Is there any chance to render a precompiled javascript file? The plain file is no problem with:

```
def iframe_communication
  render file: "/app/assets/javascripts/iframe_communication_module.js"
end
```

I tried `assets_path` or to include it with `javascript_include_tag` in the view, but no succeeds.

For clarification I don't want to add the script to my view. I try to render the javascript file for external access (adding into `<script>` tags from other domains).

**Update**

- `render file: "..."` shows the file as expected but the uncompiled version
- `assets_path "/app/assets/javascripts/iframe_communication_module.js"` returns `"/app/assets/javascripts/iframe_communication_module.js"` and not a path to the compiled asset
- `javascript_include_tag` loads the script as expected (Not Rendering)

The Rails 4 asset pipeline compiles everything into one file, is there any chance to get a single file out of it?
Or is the better way to compile it manually?

**Update 2**
Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415934/sprockets-asset-path-is-not-returning-the-digested-path-of-an-html-asset-in-pro): `assets_path` don't do what I expected. It only prepends and appends:

```
asset_path "application.js" # => /application.js  
asset_path "application", type: :javascript # => /javascripts/application.js
```

Comment: You don't show what you get when you do that. Update your question with actual results.

Comment: Sry, is it better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a working solution:

I don't need the file in the normal asset pipeline. So add

```
//= stub iframe_communication_module
```

to `apps/assets/javascript/application.js`.

To precompile the file automatically add

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( iframe_communication_module.js )
```

to `config\application.rb`

To access it through a controller add

```
redirect_to ActionController::Base.helpers.javascript_path("iframe_communication_module")
```

to the controller.