# AngularJS templates in Rails production not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, templates, asset-pipeline

I'm working with Rails(4.2) + AngularJS. Here templates fall under two category, one which is directly referenced from config.js.erb

```
 .when('/users', {
        templateUrl: '<%= asset_path("users.html") %>',
        controller: UserListCtrl
      })
```

Templates are handled properly in production and precompiled version of users template is loaded.

Others being called from inside the template like

```
<pane ng-if="$index == 0" ng-form name="chm_standard" pane-form="details.form.routing.call_handling_mode.chm_standard" heading="{{global.chm_types[0].Description}}">
   <div ng-include="'/assets/chm.html'"></div>
</pane>
```

chm.html.erb in dev mode is fetched from app/assets/javascripts/templates/en/chm.html.
This gives an error, **"Template not found"** in production since i have

> chm-fer342xx.html in public/assets/javascripts/templates

How can this be handled, is moving all templates to public/ folder only option available?

Comment: Maybe it is answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116476/rails-static-html-template-files-in-the-asset-pipeline-and-caching-in-developmen?

Answer (score 0):

When using `ng-include` angular would then only load from a trusted resource.

Possibly the browser is blocking due to CORS restrictions.

Comment: No the template is loaded, browser console gives error "Template not found" as the file is not available in path.

Comment: @Bijendra why are you referring to /assets? Put the full path public/assets/JavaScripts/templates.

Comment: same paths will not work in dev and prod as it's being fetched diffrently