# Rails precompile index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, erb, sprockets

I have `app/assets/index.html.erb` containing `<%= 'Hello world!' %>`, and added `require "sprockets/railtie"` to `config/application.rb` but when I run `rake assets:precompile` (`RAILS_ENV=development`) `public/assets` stays empty.
What am I missing?
I am also using `webpacker` and did not use `sprockets` initially.

Comment: What do you expect in `public/assets` after assets:precompile?

Comment: I would expect index.html incl. "Hello world!". I had a typo: template is in `app/assets/index.html.erb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views are not assets. Your view templates (erb, slim and etc.) will be compiled and rendered each time when rails process HTTP request. Read more about Rails views [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Assets includes only css, js, fonts, images and etc. If you have no any assets files in assets folder then "rake assets:precompile" will do nothing. More about assets pipeline [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

**UPD.** [May be this solution helps for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116476/rails-static-html-template-files-in-the-asset-pipeline-and-caching-in-developmen)

**UPD2.**

1. I create file `assets/html/index.html.erb` with <%= "Hello, world!"%>.
2. I add follow line to my `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.html.erb']
```

3. I add follow line to my manifest.js

```
//= link_directory ../html .html
```

3. I run `rake assets:precompile` and see:

```
...
I, [2019-03-31T13:56:28.979563 #50803]  INFO -- : Writing rails_app/public/assets/index-f4e7c3b6ac0beff671efa8cf84639011c06e58ca53a78d83f36107316cec125f.html
I, [2019-03-31T13:56:28.979832 #50803]  INFO -- : Writing rails_app/public/assets/index-f4e7c3b6ac0beff671efa8cf84639011c06e58ca53a78d83f36107316cec125f.html.gz
...
```

4. I open compiled file and see "Hello, world"

Comment: I do not think that is correct. Sprockets should precompile erb too. I do not need to render all views dynamically - only those who change.

Comment: @Jasper Yes, sprockets can precomplie erb, but this erb is not for views. You can use erb in css: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb or in js: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb . If you find way to compile html views to static files - give me know pls :)

Comment: You should be able to configure precompiling whatever you want, I just don't know, how.

Comment: sadly that is not working for me. I am pretty sure that is resulting from me having removed `sprockets` initially and added it manually and am now missing some important config. Where else do you reference `manifest.js` in your code?

Comment: @Jasper Manifest js required for sprocket 4. More: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs